# SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Amazon email service

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services

I want to send emails using amazon service, I am trying below code but it gives error like : SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. What could be issues here.

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

//SMTP Settings
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
$mail->Host       = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
$mail->Username   = "MY_USERNAME";
$mail->Password   = "MY_PASSWORD";

$mail->SetFrom('info@mydomain.com', 'site name'); //from (verified email address)
$mail->Subject = "Email Subject"; //subject

//message
$body = "This is a test message.";
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
//

//recipient
$mail->AddAddress("to_email_id", "to_name"); 

//Success
if ($mail->Send()) { 
    echo "Message sent!"; die; 
}

//Error
if(!$mail->Send()) { 
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I had using Gmail and I solved it by downloading the cacert.pem certificate from the site https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html You should also write the php.ini file as follows: extension = php_openssl.dll
openssl.cafile = C: \ xampp \ php \ extras \ ssl \ cacert.pem
This solution is thanks to the matteobin user contribution of stackoverflow

Comment: Ricardo, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read about [using formatting in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) so that it is easier to read.  Also, it's not clear to me that @Ketan is experiencing an SSL error... How can you tell?